# Selectable GridView Row

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView on my ASP.NET page. What I want is to execute a function when I click
on the row, and I also want to change the style of this row. I don't want to use the select button of type command field. Any help please?

Comment: Are you able to provide a few more details? Is the function in Javascript or on the server side? What are the contents of your GridViewRow?

Answer (score 1):

**For just creating a rowclickable gridview**: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/01/07/14576.aspx

You can make a TemplateField, add a linkbutton in there, make a CommandName="Select" and a CommandArgument like CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'. Then you can attach an event handler to the Gridview's ItemCommand, and do all the stuff you want to do in there, by checking the commandname and commandargument in the EventArgs.

Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="test" runat="server" onrowcommand="test_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="ActionName">Click here</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in the codebehind

```
    protected void test_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ActionName")
        {
            int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found some thing like that :
OnRowDataBound="functionName"
but it's not to clear... can you help me with this solution

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I want to fire the
function when the user click in any place over the row
without clicking a normal button

Comment: thanks a lot Jan 
but .. as I have explained in my comment I don't want to use a button
I want to fire a function when the user click any where over the row
any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

In the RowCreated event of the GridView, you're going to loop through each row as it is created:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference([grid_name], e.Row.RowIndex))
End If
```

That's about as far as I've gotten. You're going to process the event in Page_Load, but I'm in the process of working on that myself without having two grids on the same page fight with eachother. Good Luck, hope this helps. It will at least get you to postback...

Comment: I figured the rest out; here's a writeup on my blog. I hope this helps somebody:

http://patrickckozub.blogspot.com/2010/02/selectable-gridview.html